# Solving for Spring Constant Given $m_1$, $m_2$, $l_1$, and $l_2$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, spring

A spring has a length of 0.250 m when a 0.27-kg mass hangs from it, and a length of 0.920 m when a 1.86-kg mass hangs from it.

I understand how to solve it, but I do not understand why we are solving it the way I am doing it down below:

$ -kx_{1} +kx_{2} = m_{1}g - m_{2}g $

$k(x_{2} - x_{1}) = (m_{1} - m_{2})g $

$k =  \frac{(m_1 - m_2) g} {(x_{2} - x_{1})}$

For one, why is the spring constant determined by both when we know Hooke's law is:

$F = -kx$

$ mg = -kx $

Why do we have to subtract one from the other when we can solve one of them? I get there is only one spring constant for this system, but would we be constantly accounting for a mass stretching the spring at a certain length if added to the problem to find the one spring constant for this spring? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**F=-kx** is not a valid equation unless you define the symbols which are: $F$ is the force exerted **by** the spring, $k$ is the spring constant and $x$ is the **extension** of the spring which means that the force and the extension will be in opposite directions, hence the negative sign.

In the context of this question it is better to use $F=kx$ where $k$ and $x$ are defined as above but now $F$ is the force exerted **on** the spring which means that the force and the extension will be in the same direction, hence the positive sign.

In your example you have data for the mass added to the spring, $m$, and the **length** of the spring, $y$.
Let the natural length of the spring be $y_0$, ie no mass is added to the spring.
So the extension of the spring is $y-y_0$ when a mass $m$ is added.

$mg = k(y-y_0) \Rightarrow m = \frac kg\,y \,- \,\frac kg\,y_0$ which is the equation of a straight line of the form $y=mx+c$.

Drawing a sketch graph and noting what the gradient is should lead you towards an explanation of the solution to the problem?

[image]

Comment: Thank you for showing me how to communicate my Physics questions better. I definitely should have defined my variables. Thanks Farcher!!